# What does "＝" equals sign mean in Japanese news headlines?

Tags: symbols

I try to read news in Japanese and sometimes I see equals sign used inside sentences. I tend to think text to the right side of "＝" is kind of a consequence of the left part. It does not look like it has anything to do with any sort of equality. [This Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equals_sign)  notes that it can be used as the separator for names, but this usage doesn't seem to fit my case. Here is an example taken from [Jiji Press'](http://www.jiji.com/jc/c?g=spo_30&k=2015011900012) site:

> 安倍首相「どんな結果でも友好を」＝ヨルダン国王とサッカー談義.

I hope somebody can clear this out for me.

Comment: I guess you're asking about the '=' symbol in news headlines (since '=' in article body does something different). Different news organizations use different symbols: [Jiji](http://www.jiji.com/jc/c?g=soc_30&k=2015011900018) uses "=" and '-', [Yomiuri](http://www.yomiuri.co.jp/national/20150119-OYT1T50000.html) uses '…', [Asahi](http://www.asahi.com/articles/ASH1L7289H1LULBJ006.html) uses space. I think a lot of news organizations use space.

Comment: @3to5businessdays I got your point. I read news through websites, like yahoo.co.jp. As I understand when article for print is shown online it gets this separator. Does equals sign inside body works similar? I can across it too. Or do you think this question deserves a separate thread on site?

Comment: If it's in the body, the text after '=' sign explains/defines the term before the '='. For example in [this NHK article](http://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20150117/k10014763421000.html), you have things like 「ＩＯＣ＝国際オリンピック委員会」. It's quite different from when it's in the headlines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take a look at [Japanese newspapers](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%E6%96%B0%E8%81%9E&tbm=isch), you'll find that the headlines are often stratified in multiple levels. The biggest one is the eye-catcher, and the rest is some supplementary information to explain further situation.

Now, the questioned `＝` is mostly used to delimit the "main" and "sub" headlines in the one line environment. See [this topic](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1192955791) in a Japanese forum. I'm not familiar with English journalism at all, but if I had to name a closest equivalent, it could be *semicolon*, as I guess from [this page](http://web.ku.edu/~edit/heads.html).

Comment: That is a great answer. Thanks you so much! It pretty much covers it.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think it might function the same as a colon (:) does in English in a newspaper or magazine article.

> 安倍首相「どんな結果でも友好を」＝ヨルダン国王とサッカー談義.

If you saw this in a newspaper article, it would means Prime Minister Abe says "We wish mutual friendship whatever the outcome may be" = At the conversation with Jordan king about soccer.

I think it just makes a complement or something like that.

Comment: In English, we cannot use a colon in the way you are suggesting.

Comment: Oh, O.K. Thank you for that. However, I am not sure if there is any "standard" for following up supplementary or sub-titles in the world.

Comment: @KentaroTomono I understand your point. It looks likes different headings in one line is a better theory though. Thanks for your try!